# Syntax for storing environment variables in Appfile in Fastlane

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, continuous-integration, fastlane

My `Appfile` looks like this currently:

```
apple_id "myappid@domain.com"
app_identifier "com.xxx.xxx"
ENV["FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD"] = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
ENV["FASTLANE_PASSWORD"] = "myAppIdPassword"
ENV["DELIVER_USER"] = "myappid@domain.com"
ENV["FASTLANE_USER"] = "myappid@domain.com"
ENV["FASTLANE_TEAM_ID"] = "myTeamId"
```

And I have `Fastfile` like this:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Description of what the lane does"
  lane :qa do
    increment_build_number
    build_app(
        clean: true
    )
    verify_build(
       bundle_identifier: "com.xxx.xxx.project-name"
   )
   upload_to_testflight(skip_submission: true)
  end
end
```

What is happening is that when I run this from console, fastlane doesn't read from app file, and it asks me about login information. Also my apple id has two factor auth enabled, and I have created app specific password as it can be seen from Appfile, but it still doesn't work. It looks like Appfile is not parsed, or I use wrong syntax? I am getting smth like this:

```
[15:22:51]: ----------------------------------
[15:22:51]: --- Step: upload_to_testflight ---
[15:22:51]: ----------------------------------
[15:22:51]: To not be asked about this value, you can specify it using 'username'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/highline-1.7.10/lib/highline.rb:624: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
[15:22:51]: Your Apple ID Username:
```

What would be the way that I don't have to enter anything by hand in terminal prompts?

**EDIT:**

Maybe this is important... I have two factor authentication enable on my apple id. But I thought its enough to use: `FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually what worked was:

```
ENV["FASTLANE_USER"] = "myappleid@domain.com"
ENV["FASTLANE_PASSWORD"] = "xxxxxx"
ENV["FASTLANE_ITC_TEAM_ID"] = "123456789"
ENV["FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD"] = "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx"
```

the problem was with `ENV["FASTLANE_ITC_TEAM_ID"]` = "123456789" line

I didn't have quotes, it was like:

```
 ENV["FASTLANE_ITC_TEAM_ID"] = 123456789
```

and obviously file was not parsed good, and each time I was asked for my apple id credentials -_-

Comment: How would I call the ENV from outside the Appfile?

Answer (score 6):

I recently worked with fastlane , here is what I used

```
app_identifier("com.xxx.xxx") # The bundle identifier of your app
apple_id("myappid@domain.com") # Your Apple email address

itc_team_id(“123456”) # App Store Connect Team ID
team_id(“1a2”d3f5g6g) # Developer Portal Team ID
```